# Check GPRS availability on windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

I want to check that GPRS avaibility between specific time interval in windows mobile. I tried code which request google every 30 seconds using timer but it hangs system and seems costly to check every 30 seconds.. Is there any other way I can get it done? and do not hang my system.

Answer (score 0):

If youe development environment is .NET, you can use the SystemState class to monitor for changes on the following SystemProperties:

```
ConnectionsCellularCount
ConnectionsCellularDescriptions
```

see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.aspx for more information.

Comment: I used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.phonegprscoverage.aspx
to check it.